# PHP And MySQL Insert error: ucp is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, html, mysql

today i finished working on my markup and started writing code, i wrote this simple code for registration but when user clicks on submit button they see error:

> This page isn’t working
>   ucp.ls-rp.ge is currently unable to handle this request. 
>   HTTP ERROR 500

How can this be solved?
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
<?
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'lsrpge14_forum';
$pass = 'lsrpgeforum123.';
$db = 'lsrpge14_forum';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
/* CREATE CHARACTER FUNCTIONS */
$sex = 0;

function IsRPName($name, $max_underscores = 1)
{
    $underscores = 0;
    if ($name[0] < 'A' || $name[0] > 'Z') return false;
    for($i = 1; $i < strlen($name); $i++)
    {
    if($name[$i] != '_' && ($name[$i] < 'A' || $name[$i] > 'Z') && ($name[$i] < 'a' || $name[$i] > 'z')) return false;
    if( ($name[$i] >= 'A' && $name[$i] <= 'Z') && ($name[$i - 1] != '_') ) return false;
    if($name[$i] == '_')
    {
    $underscores++;
    if($underscores > $max_underscores || $i == strlen($name)) return false;
    if($name[$i + 1] < 'A' || $name[$i + 1] > 'Z') return false;
    }
    }
    if ($underscores == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
function SendCharacterAplication($ownerid, $name, $sex, $explainmg, $explainpg, $charbio)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Aplicants (ownerid, charname, sex explainmg, explainpg, charbio) " . "VALUES ('$ownerid', '$name', '$sex', '$explainmg', '$explainpg', '$charbio')";
    if ($mysqli->query($sql) ){
        $_SESSION['createcharerror'] = "<h2 style='color:green'>თქვენი პერსონაჟი წარმატებით შეიქმნა! დაელოდეთ ადმინისტრაციის პასუხს!</h2>";
        header("location: profile.php"); 

    }

    header("location: index.php");
}

/* CREATE CHARACTER CHECK VALUES */

if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['createcharerror'] = "<h2 style='color:red'>პროფილის სანახავად გაიარეთ ავტორიზაცია!</h2>";
  header("location: index.php");    
}

if ( $_SESSION['countchars'] == 2)
{
    $_SESSION['createcharerror'] = "<h2 style:'color:red'>თქვენ უკვე გაქვთ გაკეთებული 2 პერსონაჟი!</h2>";
    header("location: index.php");
}

if(is_null($_POST['charname']))
{
    $_SESSION['createcharerror'] = "<h2 style:'color:red'>ჩაწერეთ პერსონაჟის სახელი!</h2>";
    header("location: index.php");
}

if(!IsRPName($_POST['charname']))
{
    $_SESSION['createcharerror'] = "<h2 style='color:red;'>პერსონაჟის ნიკი არ არის სწორ ფორმატში Firstname_Lastname!</h2>";
    header("location: index.php");
}

if(is_null($_POST['gender']))
{
    $_SESSION['createcharerror'] = "<h2 style='color:red;'>მონიშნეთ პერსონაჟის სქესი!</h2>";
    header("location: index.php");
}

if($_POST['gender'] == 'male')
{
    $sex = 1;
}
else
{
    $sex = 2;
}

if(str_word_count($_POST['charbio']) < 70)
{
    $_SESSION['createcharerror'] = "<h2 style='color:red'>პერსონაჟის ბიოგრაფია არ უნდა იყოს 70 სიტყვა-ზე ნაკლები!</h2>";
    header("location: index.php");
}
else{
    SendCharacterAplication($_SESSION['masterid'], $_POST['charname'], $sex, $_POST['explainmg'], $_POST['explainpg'], $_POST['charbio']);
}
```

Comment: The first thing you always do on a 500 Internal Server Error, is go check the server’s log files.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting a 500 error because the server is configured to repress SQL errors. If you have a look at your error logs or output the SQL being run and run it manually you may be able to see the exact error.

You must sanitize any values passed into SQL from user input, any use of an apostrophe in any of those fields will result in an SQL error (or worse SQL injection).

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

It's also possible you've got the table name wrong compared to what's in the database; Aplicants should have 2 p's

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.